# Using accented characters in Libre Office (Ubuntu character mapping)

Tags: keyboard, libreoffice, settings

I read on the Internet that I could set up Ubuntu to use characters like á and é by assigning <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> as the Alternative Characters Key in keyboard settings. It works in nearly all applications.

But when I search for a word in Libre Office - in the search window, the accented character wipes out whatever stands before it. Eg if you search for étais - it's fine - as é comes first. If I type été in the search window - the final é wipes out the ét and I am left with just é.

For some reason, LibreOffice wants the Alternative Characters Key to overwrite everything else in the search box.

Comment: Is this just this search box, or does it happen in, say, gedit or calc?

Comment: It is just in the search box in Libre Office.